# Is there any way to increase the efficiency of IBM Watson speech-to-text engine for understanding different frequencies?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am using IBM Watson `speech-to-text` `API`. There are different frequencies of different people in speech. Is Watson capable of detecting different frequencies of people?

Answer (score 0):

The Speech to Text service just released a speaker labels feature that may address what you're interested in:

http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/output.shtml#speaker_labels

Please take a look to see whether this new feature provides what you need.

Thanks!